# EntityFramework avoid open/close connection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there any easy way to avoid open and close connection when using code like this :

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
                {
                    returnValue = context.ExecuteStoreCommand(sqlStr, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return returnValue;
                }
```

I have alot of code like this in diffrent methods that need to be runned in a massive database(MySQL update. It would go much faster if it did not open/close connection between each method (using/SaveChanges).

Maby I have to change the code entirely and place the context as a static member and then remove the using from all the methods? Or is there a easy setting?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063730/best-way-to-initialize-an-entity-framework-context

Answer (score 0):

you should go with unit of work pattern. by using unit of work pattern you are able to create transactional calls to database.

[unit of work pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)